# How to programmatically add a builder to a project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I would like to add a custom builder to an existing project. What I have is the name of the builder (e.g. com.example.myBuilder) as declared in the plugin.xml and a reference to the `IProject`.

```java
String builderName = "com.example.myBuilder";
IProject project = ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Builders are specified in the project description. The project description is stored in a file named `.project` in XML form.

Therein a socalled *buildSpec* controls what should be done when the project or parts thereof should be built. It consists ofa list of *commands* and each command denotes a *builder* that is executed at build time.

The snippet below adds a new builder `com.example.myBuilder` to the list of existing commands.

```java
IProjectDescription projectDescription = project.getDescription();
ICommand[] buildSpec = projectDescription.getBuildSpec();
ICommand command = projectDescription.newCommand();
command.setBuilderName( "com.example.myBuilder" );
Collection<ICommand> list = new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( buildSpec ) );
list.add( command );
projectDescription.setBuildSpec( list.toArray( new ICommand[ list.size() ] ) );
project.setDescription( projectDescription, new NullProgressMonitor() );
```

After modifying the project description, the changes need to be persisted with `project.setDescription()` in order to take effect

Unfortunately there is no `addCommand` method, therefore the laborious array to list to array forth and back.